# setting default value to radio button php

Tags: php, html

i want to set a default value to radio buttons for my form. the default value should match the value from database. i know how to set default value that is my by using checked="checked". in my case, the problem lies in how to use database value as default in radiobuttons.

```
<tr>
    <td>ASP.NET</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="not at all competent" ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="little competent" ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="moderately competent"</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="extremely competent"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The syntax is the same. What is your problem with database? Please edit post adding table structure and your database query

Comment: Show the code you are using to get the value from the database.

Comment: let me explain in a better way what i want to do. i have a value of asp.net stored in a table. i fetch that value using query and store it in an array using mysqli_fetch_array($result). now i want that fetched value must be default value which one of four values mentioned in the row. hope u get it now

Comment: this is the code that i am using:

Comment: $query="select * from technical_skills where student_id='$student_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query); $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like the following:

```
<?php
//Retrieve your value here

$query="select * from technical_skills where student_id='$student_id'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
// Assign the column to the variable
$dbValue = $row['columnname'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>ASP.NET</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="not at all competent"<?php echo ($dbValue=='not at all competent'?' checked=checked':''); ?> ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="little competent"<?php echo ($dbValue=='little competent'?' checked=checked':''); ?> ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="moderately competent"<?php echo ($dbValue=='moderately competent'?' checked=checked':''); ?> ></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="asp" value="extremely competent"<?php echo ($dbValue=='extremely competent'?' checked=checked':''); ?> ></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You commented out the $dbValue assignment.

Answer (score -1):

You can define an empty variable for each option and set them to 'checked=checked' according to the DB returned value.

example:

```
$not_competent = ''
if($dbResult == 'not_competent') $not_competent = 'checked=checked';
```

Do the same with the other options and then print the table.

> Write the table between "..." so PHP can pharse the variables and show
>   the proper info

```
print "<tr>
    <td>ASP.NET</td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='asp' value='not at all competent' $not_competent></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='asp' value='little competent' $little competent></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='asp' value='moderately competent' $moderately_competent></td>
    <td><input type='radio' name='asp' value='extremely competent' $extremely_competent></td>
</tr>";
```

Cheers!